# Execute Remote Command just Once a Day for zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I want to execute action once in a day. Like whenever day's 1st alert is present in the Zabbix that time Action will restart the service/process. After that suppose same alert is come in Zabbix that time no Action will performed that time.

I am using Zabbix version 6.2.4 and on client side it is zabbix-agent2
I have created the Action on the trigger.
item --> get information process is running or not.

```
system.run["ps -aux | grep -i 'proces' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l"]
```

trigger --> When process is down that time trigger id generated.

```
last(/Monitor process/system.run["ps -aux | grep -i 'proces' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l"])<1
```

0 indicate --> Through the alert in Zabbix
1 indicate --> do not do anything.

Action --> When trigger is present in the Zabbix Action execute the service start script.

Up to this point all function is working fine.

But I want this action only once in a day. Like whenever day's 1st alert is present in the Zabbix that time Action will restart the service/process.

Answer (score 0):

Problem history is not available as an Action condition, so you don't know in Zabbix if the Event already triggered, and when. You can however manage it inside the restart script.

Following script restarts the service when it's been more than 24 hours since last restart.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
SEMAPHORE=/tmp/zabbix.service1.lastrestart
first_time=0
day=$(expr 24 \* 60 \* 60)
delta=$(expr $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y $SEMAPHORE 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null)

if [ -z "$delta" ]; then
  # file doesn't exists
  first_time=1
elif [ $delta -gt $day ] ; then
  # more than 1d since last restart
  first_time=1
fi

if [ $first_time -eq 1 ]; then
  systemctl restart service1
  touch $SEMAPHORE

fi
```

Please note that `system.run[]` is deprecated, you should use it for tests only. In this case the appropriate key may be `proc.num[]`, or even `systemd.unit.info[]` since you are using Agent2 newer than 4.4 (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.2/en/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/examples/systemd?hl=systemd).